# How to catch non-primary key exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, primary-key

The problem I am facing now is when a user types in the same email,it will still register the member. I do not want my email to be set as a primary key.Is there a way for me to stop the process if a person enter the same email under the try/catch statement?

```
public string registerMember()
{
    string status = "";
    string ConnString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;

    string sql = "INSERT INTO Member (userName,Email,Gender,DateOfBirth,Nationality) VALUES(@name, @email, @gender, @dateOfBirth, @nationality)";

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand((sql), cn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfBirth", dateOfBirth);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", nationality);

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
            status = "Member have been registered successfully!"; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status = ex.Message;
            throw;    
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return status;

}
```

Comment: Simply add UNIQUE index on your email column

Comment: You can do it but not in `try catch()`. You can validate first through your database if there is already an email stop your process otherwise do you `INSERT`

Comment: Yes that is the one i meant!Is it possible you show me the demo code because i am begginner here. :(

Comment: May I ask why you have a message announcing successful insertion of the record in your 'finally' block?  The 'finally' block is executed after successor failure, so that is not the place for it.  You only know that you've been successful if you read the end of the 'try' block, so that should be the place that you specify success.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling Dispose on the command anyway.  You've already got a 'using' block so use it to create and destroy the command as well as the connection.

Comment: Noted jmcilhinney.Thanks for correcting it! :)

Comment: write function like `static bool ismailExist(string email)` inside the function check in your database if it exists return true otherwise false. Now before `INSERT`, use `if (ismailExist(txtEmail.Text){ return; }` otherwise do your `INSERT`

Comment: so that means i must have an if..else statement in the try right?

Comment: no not in the `try`. You must use `if..else` before calling `registerMember()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write another database query, and check if e-mail already exists my friend.

Comment: I try from just now but i cant. I really hope you can write for me the code because i am really new to this.